# How to Modify URL Structure in WordPress for GET Method Form Submission?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

How can I modify the URL structure in WordPress when using the GET method for form submission? Currently, when I submit the form, the URL appears as http://localhost/c/?name1=5paisa&name2=zerodha, but I want this type of URL http://localhost/c/5paisa-vs-zerodha.

Comment: You can't do it by only modifying the URL structure. You need to override the form submit using Javascript, or you can create a redirect using PHP when form is submitting. Imo, URL rewriting is useful for SEO, but kind of useless for forms.